# What are some paid cryptocurrency exchange software?

Tags: blockchain, exchanges, exchange-software

What are major exchanges are using ?
few of them have similar layout and trading system.

is there readymade crypto trading software available ? even paid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ready-made crypto trading software is available. I have been shortlisted some of the crypto trading software provider across the world.

Coinsclone

BitExchange System

Trading Technologies

Draglet

BlockchainAppFactory